# Using a parameter in a Sample Clause for SSRS developed in Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, plsql, sample

I'm attempting to give the end user control over sample size to meet their needs. On any given day their needs can vary from less than 10 to over 200. But I can't get an open parameter to work with `SAMPLE`. It insists that either an integer or `WHEN` keyword must follow `SAMPLE`.

I have a parameter `SAMPLE_SIZE` set to INTEGER with no default values.
`SAMPLE 10` selects 10 results. But `SAMPLE ?` gives an error that an INTEGER must follow `SAMPLE`. `SAMPLE WHEN ?=10 THEN 10 WHEN ?=100 THEN 100 ELSE 200 END` will work. But only gives the sample size options I set and isn't versatile enough to meet the needs.

```
SELECT *
FROM shared_extracts.data_table
SAMPLE 10
```

This works, but replacing the 10 with a ? and pointing the ? to `Sample_Size` parameter always results in the error,

> "Expecting an Integer or WHEN keyword"

I want it to work in Preview where the end user can type in any number and the report will use that number to set the sample size.

Comment: Have you tried to use dynamic SQL?